# Make a script only log once a minute but runs every second

Tags: php, timer, daemon

I have a php script that checks the database every second(ish as not 100% important its on second) and writes the output to json files for a captioning system. This has a success log file

I want to log the quite times too.

I was logging to the last line with "." every time it ran.

```
2012-06-18 10:45:51 UTC | .........................
```

This can lead to very long line which might break future log checking system.

So I have change this for a line that runs every 5 minutes

```
// 2012-06-18 10:45:51 UTC | wait.
if ((int) date('i') % 5 == 0) 
{
log ( $date . ' | wait. ' );
}
```

but this logs every second/iteration of every 5th minute. I could add seconds but it does not always run every 01 second.

Is there a way of logging once in n time?

Comment: I guess a sub question is how often is it good to log a script is running in order to look back for any outages? Maybe a summed average of 5min/10min/60min like a unix top command might be better to graph than just a stream of yes every second ....

Comment: Doubt you will be able to accurately check for outages if running every hour. Once per second seemed quite reasonable. It shouldn't be of much resources used.

Comment: Doens't it work when you put in a sleep method? => sleep(5 * 60);

Answer (score 1):

You could have your script write to a secondary temporary file its last run time.  Then on next execution, it can load that value, compute the difference from the current time and that stored value and if it is greater than N, log your entry to the log file.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar as its a command line script and not a webpage I dont think I can do sessions. I could write the next log interval to file and log update to log. Then check file until next interval was true, log and update to next interval.